# The python says " 'property' object has no attribute 'format'"

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark

I am trying to use spark and I am stuck on the reading the data..

here is my code..

```
df = SQLContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
                .options(header='true', inferSchema='true')\
                .load('C:/....')
```

and the error message says that

'property' object has no attribute 'format'

So I think there are something wrong with format.. I tried to read the code of spark but it was just too hard.

I will really appreciate if anybody helps me a little.

Comment: @Srinivas Thanks I tried but same error message occured..

Comment: When I tried the first code, it says that "Java gateway process exited before sending its port number" and when I tried the second code, it says that name 'spark' is not defined..

Comment: updated code , check now.

Comment: @Srinivas I really appreciate your help, but It says that "Java gateway process exited before seding its port number.. again when I define the spark. , the 2nd line of your code.

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: to fix that issue check this issue -https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743

Comment: @Srinivas My spark version is 3.0.0 and I didnt download java, should I install Java to use python..?

Comment: how you installed spark ?

Comment: @Srinivas I installed spark through cmd, I typed " pip install spark " on the command line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("sample").getOrCreate()

df = spark\
.read\
.format("csv")\
.options(header = 'true', inferSchema = 'true')\
.load("D:\\tmp\\data\\sample")
```

My Spark Version 2.4.3

```
λ pyspark
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
      /_/

Using Python version 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019 21:26:53)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("sample").getOrCreate()
>>> df = spark.read.format("csv").options(header = 'true', inferSchema = 'true').load("D:\\tmp\\data\\sample\\country_codes.csv")
>>> df.show()
+-------------------+-----+-----+
|       country_name|iso_2|iso_3|
+-------------------+-----+-----+
|        Afghanistan|   AF|  AFG|
|      �land Islands|   AX|  ALA|
|            Albania|   AL|  ALB|
|            Algeria|   DZ|  DZA|
|     American Samoa|   AS|  ASM|
|            Andorra|   AD|  AND|
|             Angola|   AO|  AGO|
|           Anguilla|   AI|  AIA|
|         Antarctica|   AQ|  ATA|
|Antigua and Barbuda|   AG|  ATG|
|          Argentina|   AR|  ARG|
|            Armenia|   AM|  ARM|
|              Aruba|   AW|  ABW|
|          Australia|   AU|  AUS|
|            Austria|   AT|  AUT|
|         Azerbaijan|   AZ|  AZE|
|            Bahamas|   BS|  BHS|
|            Bahrain|   BH|  BHR|
|         Bangladesh|   BD|  BGD|
|           Barbados|   BB|  BRB|
+-------------------+-----+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```